# how to Load Text file into HTML, inside <textarea> tag?

Tags: html

how to Load Text file into HTML, inside  tag?, I don't have an source to show you.
**thanks**

Comment: Where is the text file? On the user's computer? On the server? On another server?

Comment: text file from user's computer, I don't know if load on other web server url like: a.com/b.txt, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP to load files from the user's computer. Here is an example.

form.html

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";  
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        header("Location: http://example.com/displaymessage.php?filename=" + basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

displaymessage.php

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['filename'];
?>
<script>
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/uploads/<?=$file?>');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  document.getElementById("#textbox").value = client.responseText;
}
client.send();
</script>
```

Make sure to change `#textbox`, to the ID of the textarea tag. (e.g. `<textarea id="foo">`)
NOTE: I just came up with half of this code, and I am not sure if it will work

Comment: where can i get (button) to load file? please explain or add all html script

Comment: @SchoolforDesgin To load a file from your own computer, you should use PHP. PHP can be used to submit files, and can be seen in many websites. After you get the file with PHP, you can copy it into your initial directory, and then get it with JavaScript, as mentioned above.

Comment: Please mark it as correct, if this solved your question.